# Derived Column Expression in ssis

Tags: sql, ssis

If Company Name is 'NULL' then populate as "Person", if CompanyName is Not null then populate as "Company".

I tried this
CustomerType (CompanyName == "Null" ? "Person" : (CompanyName == "NotNull" ? "Company" ))

I want to use derived column in ssis

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ISNULL([CompanyName])? [Person] : [Company]
```

The ternary operator reads as `(test) ? (true value) : (false value)` .

The pseudo-logic for what you have written is: if the company name is the literal string Null, the use the string Person. Otherwise, if the company name is the literal string NotNull, then use the literal string Company.

This answer can be read as: if the result of the ISNULL function returns true, use the column Person. Else use the column Company.